# Rails 5.2 Array Not Saving (unpermitted parameter) even though permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a series of checkboxes on my `blog/_form.html.erb` which, using Javascript/JQuery update a `hidden_field_tag` for `:subcategory_ids`.

The hidden field looks like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :subcategory_ids %>
```

And according to Google code inspector the value is getting updated:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1,5,6" name="blog[subcategory_ids]" id="blog_subcategory_ids">
```

I have the following `blog` structure in my `schema.rb`:

```
 create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "teaser"
    t.text "body"
    t.boolean "motivation", default: false
    t.boolean "mindset", default: false
    t.boolean "resourcing", default: false
    t.boolean "planning", default: false
    t.boolean "time_management", default: false
    t.boolean "discipline", default: false
    t.string "image_url"
    t.text "pinterest_description"
    t.boolean "published", default: false
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.boolean "approved", default: false
    t.boolean "featured", default: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "primary_category"
    t.bigint "resource_id"
    t.string "subcategory_ids", array: true
    t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_resource_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_user_id"
  end
```

And the following params in my `blogs_controller.rb`:

```
def blog_params
  params.require(:blog).permit(
    :title,
    :teaser,
    :body,

    :primary_category,
    :motivation,
    :mindset,
    :resourcing,
    :planning,
    :time_management,
    :discipline,

    :image_url,
    :pinterest_description,

    :published,
    :published_at,
    :featured,
    :approved,

    :resource_id,
    :user_id,

    :pins => [],
    :subcategory_ids => []
  )
end
```

However, my `subcategory_ids` don't seem to be saving due to an `unpermitted parameter: :subcategory_ids` error in my server:

```
Started PATCH "/blogs/1" for ::1 at 2019-11-08 21:33:43 -0800
Processing by BlogsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VDXdyzAYmVngd5at8QE4JIe09PeEuMi6+p99AFX8nv2iO3qIXGUEDId1jnGyRXR3h8vXLVjG/EUuGtHFxAt03A==", "blog"=>{"title"=>"Test Blog the First", "teaser"=>"Teaser Goes Here.  Yes, all the things. Yes indeed-e-o.  Words are being typed.  By me.", "image_url"=>"https://sixkeyskills.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/woman-arms-up-ocean.jpg", "body"=>"<p data-bind=\"text: generatedIpsum\">Blog text</p>", "primary_category"=>"General", "motivation"=>"1", "mindset"=>"1", "resourcing"=>"0", "planning"=>"0", "time_management"=>"0", "discipline"=>"0", "subcategory_ids"=>"1,5,6", "pinterest_description"=>"", "published_at"=>"2019-11-07 00:00:00 UTC", "published"=>"1", "approved"=>"1", "featured"=>"0", "resource_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
  Blog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:112
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:103
   (41.0ms)  SELECT "subcategories"."id" FROM "subcategories" INNER JOIN "blog_categorizations" ON "subcategories"."id" = "blog_categorizations"."subcategory_id" WHERE "blog_categorizations"."blog_id" = $1  [["blog_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:73
Unpermitted parameter: :subcategory_ids
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:82
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:82
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:82
```

This is weird because it shows that the edited blog DOES have `subcategory_ids`, but then later says it's an unpermitted parameter.

I have restarted my server, but to no avail.  Can anyone see why this error is happening or why it isn't saving?

Comment: Your `subcategory_ids` param is not an array. It's a string with value `"1,5,6"`.

Answer (score 0):

because in the controller you wait for an array, but not array comes.
your input in the form should look something like this:

```
blog[subcategory_ids] []
```

or try to write the field `multiple: true`
or change in the controller

```
:subcategory_ids => []
```

to

```
:subcategory_ids
```

more variant:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :categories, value: 1, multiple: true %>
<%= form.hidden_field :categories, value: 2, multiple: true %>
<%= form.hidden_field :categories, value: 3, multiple: true %>
```

and controller:

```
:subcategory_ids => []
```

Comment: If I add `multiple: true` to the `hidden_field` it saves the first item in the array, but not the others.  So closer, but still slightly off...

Comment: try write in form field:
f.hidden_field :subcategory_ids, name: "blog[subcategory_ids][][subcategory_id]", multiple: true

can be without multiple: true

Comment: Hmmm...that one yielded `"subcategory_ids"=>[{"subcategory_id"=>"3,6,9"}]` in the server log and gave me a `subcategory_id` value of `[4, 4]`.  So bizarre.

Comment: try in the form and in the controller to remove all indications that it is an array.
because you have already specified in the model that it is an array.

Comment: I get `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>` errrors if I change the params list in the controller, and we already tested that without `multiple: true` it doesn't save anything.

Comment: try to write the field: as: :array, instead multiple: true
and remove in the controller in permit the instruction that it is an array.

Comment: see my first post, I added another option how the form should look.
you need to have a separate field for each element of the array.

Comment: try write in form: "name: blog[subcategory_ids] [][subcategory_id], multiple: true" and in controller: "subcategory_ids: [:subcategory_id]"